# Openapi-ui swagger example generating as null

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

Migrating from Springfox to Openapi.
The Swagger document is generated, but the request and response example is showing as null. whereas schema definition shows proper.
Is there any internal dependency required which is converting the schema to JSON.

**Example Value** | Schema

null

Comment: Please post your controller and schema code with annotations. If you updated the annotations during migration, post both the old and new code.